# Make Apache log virtualhost traffic in both /virtuserdir/access_log and /var/log/httpd/access_log

Tags: apache, logging, virtualhost

I know I can make apache log traffic for a virtualhost by defining it in VirtualHosts config like this:

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1>
DocumentRoot /home/virtuser/html
ServerName www.virtdomain.org
CustomLog /home/virtuser/logs/access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

However, then that virtualhost's traffic is not longer logged in the main file /var/log/http/access_log.

Is there a way to make it so its (both access and error) logged in both places?

The webdevelopers would like realtime access to the apache logs for debugging html pages so they want the virtualhost logfiles, but it'd be easier for me on the admin side if all hits are logged in 1 file for gathering stats, watching for hack attempts etc.